# Which function(s) should I use for getting input from the keyboard?

Tags: c, input

I am learning C and now I want to get input from the keyboard (2 numbers range [0,99] and compare them). I found plenty of options for getting input:

- scanf()
- getchar()
- fgets()
- gets()

I tried some of them:

**Scanf:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()  
{
int flag=0,num1, num2;

printf("Give a number between 0-999");

do{

    if(flag == 1){
       printf("Wrong Input. Plz give a number between 0-99 ");    
    }   
    printf("\nnumber 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    flag=1;   
}while(num1<0 || num1>1000);

printf("Give one more");
flag=0;

do{

    if(flag == 1){
       printf("Wrong Input. Plz give a number between 0-99 ");    
    }   
    printf("\nnumber 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    flag=1;   
}while(num2<0 || num2>1000);

if(num1>num2){
    printf("the max number is : %d\n", num1);
}else 
    if (num1<num2){
        printf("the max number is : %d\n", num2);
    }else
        printf("they are equals\n");
```

}

However, if I press a not a number, it prints infinitely:

> number 2: Wrong Input. Plz give a number between 0-99
>   number 2: Wrong Input. Plz give a number between 0-99 
>   number 2: Wrong Input. Plz give a number between 0-99 
>   // and goes on..

Then I tried to use **getchar:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
int flag=0;
char input1,input2;

printf("Give a number between 0-999");

do{

    if(flag == 1){
       printf("Wrong Input. Plz give a number between 0-99 ");    
    }   
    printf("\nnumber 1: ");
    input1 = getchar();
    flag=1;   
}while(input1<0 || input1>1000);

printf("Give one more");
flag=0;

do{

    if(flag == 1){
       printf("Wrong Input. Plz give a number between 0-99 ");    
    }   
    printf("\nnumber 2: ");
    input1 = getchar();
    flag=1;   
}while(input2<0 || input2>1000);

if(input1>input2){
    printf("the max number is : %c\n", input1);
}else 
    if (input1<input2){
        printf("the max number is : %c\n", input2);
    }else
        printf("they are equals\n");


}
```

but this code doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: try gets(), also you can encapsulate the reading of the number in a function to avoid code duplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of values successfully scanned, or `-1` on an error. So if `scanf` doesn't return `1` then something went wrong, and you should act accordingly.

---

The problem with `getchar` is that it returns a character (or `EOF` on error. So if you enter a number only the first digit will be returned, and as a characters and not a number. The second call to `getchar` will then return the second digit from the first input, as a character.

---

I would suggest the input function would look something like this instead:

```
int get_input(void)
{
    /* Infinite loop */
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Please enter a value between 1 and 9999 (inclusive): ");
        fflush(stdout);

        char buffer[256];

        /* Read input from the user */
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error getting input");
            return -1;
        }

        int value;

        /* Extract an integer value from the input */
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &value) != 1)
        {
            printf("Your input was not a valid value.\n");
            continue;  /* Try to get input again */
        }

        /* Check for a valid value */
        if (value >= 1 && value <= 9999)
            return value;  /* Got a value that is allowed */

        printf("Not a valid value.\n");
        /* Since we're in a loop, will continue from the beginning by asking for a value */
    }

    return -1;  /* Must return a value */
}
```

Call this function to get a value, and if it returns -1 then there was an error:

```
int value1;
if ((value1 = get_input()) == -1)
    exit(1);  /* Error reading value */
```

Comment: i didnt know that! nice! @JoachimPileborg :) But How i will make check it? (by checking the variable num1?)

Comment: since i do the check in the while statement, in case the scanf would return -1, it should loop again..

Comment: @Nat95 If `scanf` returns `EOF` (e.g. `-1`) that can either mean end-of-file *or* it can mean there is an error. In either case you can't continue in that situation. If on the other hand, `scanf` return `0` then you should skip the input (using e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read into a dummy buffer) and tell the user to input a proper number.

Comment: @Nat95 As a matter of fact, I would actually recommend to use `fgets` to get the input from the user, and then use `sscanf` to try and extract a number.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39828/discussion-between-nat95-and-joachim-pileborg)

Comment: 2 questions for the lines 11and 19 (the 2 if statements). In the 1st  if statement, in case of wrong input, what will be the returned value of `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)` ?

in the 2nf if statement, why are you comparing it with the value 1??
`sscanf(buffer, "%d", &value) != 1`

Comment: @Nat95 Updated the code to explicitly compare the result from `fgets` with `NULL`, as `fgets` returns `NULL` on any kind of error.  In the second `if` I compare agains `1` because I scan for one item. If `sscanf` doesn't return `1` then there was some kind of problem scanning that one item.

Comment: one more question @JoachimPileborg ! in the 2nd if statement, the `continue` command you have, means : do the check, if is true do again the check? or it goes again from the loop?

Comment: @Nat95 The `continue` statement continues the loop immediately, so it will jump back to the beginning of the loop and print the prompt again.